# Calling one nodejs module from the other

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have the following setup, test.html, test_bar.js, test_foo.js :

```js
   /* test_bar.js */
    BAR = {
      init: function() {
         console.log("BAR LOADED!");
         /* I'd like to call FOO.hello(); here */
      }
    };

    $(function() {
      $(window).load(function() {
        BAR.init();
      });

    });

    /* test_foo.js */
    FOO = {
      init: function() {
       console.log("FOOO LOADED");
       },
      hello: function(){ 
       console.log("hello I'm FOO");
      }
    };

    $(function() {
      $(window).load(function() {
        Foo.init();
      });

    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>FOO BAR HELP</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/test_bar.js"></script>
        <script src="js/test_foo.js"></script>
    </html>
```

and I keep getting the following error:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Foo is not defined
        at test_foo.js:9
        at dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
        at r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I suspect it's because I'm doing window.load, twice (once in each .js) and trying to call FOO before it has been loaded. I should note that the code base is inherited and that I'd like to keep FOO and BAR in separate .js files.

How can I refactor the design so that I can call functions such as FOO.hello(); from BAR ?

Thanks

Comment: `Foo` vs `FOO`  looks like a typo.

Comment: Correct! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You define object name as FOO, but call it as Foo.

```
FOO = {
    init: function() {
        console.log('foo loaded');
    }
}

$( function() {
    FOO.init(); // "foo loaded"
});
```

If you want to call FOO within BAR then you have to include FOO before BAR like so:

```
<script src="js/test_foo.js"></script>
<script src="js/test_bar.js"></script>
```

Comment: If this is all the issue was, then this question is subject to being closed due to a typo, not answered.